# Python print items from a feed matching 1 hour after current time

Tags: python, time

I was messing a little with Json on Python, I wanted to read the [API](http://api.tvmaze.com/schedule?country=US&date=2017-07-17) provided by tvmaze.com. While I can get the items just fine, the list is kind of long, I want to limit it to +1 hour from my local clock. for instance, if my computer clock is 15:00 to show me the items from 16:00 so at 15:30 it would show me the items with 16:30. in php, i would add 3,600 seconds to the current time, but in python, the whole time-delta seems confusing.

Here is the Python code i am currently using

```
import urllib2
import simplejson

response = urllib2.urlopen("http://api.tvmaze.com/schedule?country=US&date=2017-07-17")
data = simplejson.load(response)
myList=["abc","amc","animal planet","bravo","cartoon network","cbs","comedy central","the cw","discovery channel","fox","freeform","hbo","history","mtv","nbc","nickelodeon","tbs","tnt","usa network","wwe network"]
for post in data:
    if post["show"]["network"]["name"].lower() in myList:
        airtime = post["airtime"]
        network = post["show"]["network"]["name"]
        name = post["show"]["name"]
        season = post["season"]
        ep = post["number"]
        time = post["show"]["schedule"]["time"]
        date = post["airdate"]
        #summary = ["show"]["summary"]
        print airtime,"",name,"- Season",season,"EP",ep,"("+network+")"
```

Sample output:

```
21:00  Preacher - Season 2 EP 5 (AMC)
21:00  Will - Season 1 EP 3 (TNT)
21:00  American Pickers - Season 17 EP 10 (History)
21:00  Stitchers - Season 3 EP 6 (FreeForm)
21:00  Superhuman - Season 1 EP 6 (FOX)
21:00  Whose Line Is It Anyway? - Season 13 EP 6 (The CW)
21:00  Teen Mom 2 - Season 8 EP 1 (MTV)
21:00  Street Outlaws: New Orleans - Season 2 EP 4 (Discovery Channel)
21:00  The Real Housewives of Orange County - Season 12 EP 2 (Bravo)
21:00  Teen Mom - Season 7 EP 30 (MTV)
21:00  Alaska: The Last Frontier: The Frozen Edge - Season 4 EP 13 (Animal Planet)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily obtain your current time and add any offset to it using the `datetime` module, e.g.:

```
import datetime

current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()  # local date and time
current_time = datetime.datetime.time(current_datetime)  # time only
plus_hour = datetime.datetime.time(current_datetime + datetime.timedelta(hours=1))  # +1h
```

Now, if you want to 'filter' on that, you can always turn the data from the API you're calling into a time object and then compare, but in your case for an exact time all you need is to compare the hour and the minute of the entry to your `plus_hour` time, for example:

```
split_time = post["airtime"].split(":")  # split the time field
time_hour = time_minute = 0  # initialize as both as `0`
if len(split_time) >= 2:
    time_hour = int(split_time[0])
    time_minute = int(split_time[1])
elif len(split_time) > 0:
    time_hour = int(split_time[0])
if int(time_hour) != plus_hour.hour and int(time_minute) != plus_hour.minute:
    continue  # no match, move to the next item...
```

Comment: I am obviously doing it wrong because i get an error ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack.

Comment: Than it means that some `post["airtime"]` doesn't contain a valid time, check the update.

Comment: how would i implement that with my code? add the if and elif inside the for loop?

Comment: @Slightz - if you add the above instead of your `airtime = post["airtime"]`, it will automatically skip all the entries that are not exactly an hour after the current time. Make sure that you address the lack of `airtime` variable later on in the code if you replace its setting with this code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm doing it wrong. https://gyazo.com/df7aa4b98ca5ae7b7c03b76dd6209712

the airtime = post["airtime"] it was a variable i made so i can print airtime instead of print post["airtime"]

Comment: @Slightz - There was a typo in the script (`lent()` instead of `len()`), updated.

Comment: I get the same error, so it's obvious I am placing the code wrong.

http://rextester.com/FNC24140

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149425/discussion-between-zwer-and-slightz).

Answer (score 0):

The time-delta may seem confusing but it's the best tool for the job.

Here's the approach I usually take when dealing with timedeltas in Python. Hopefully this will be more readable to you.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> now = datetime.utcnow()
>>> def hour_past(dt):
...     return dt + timedelta(hours=1)
...
>>> hour_from_now = hour_past(now)
>>> hour_from_now > now
True
```

Admittedly, it's with `datetime`s and not `time`s, but that's just what I personally prefer because of `utcnow()`'s reliability.